# Mapped keys not working in Finder

Tags: keyboard, mapping

I am using a keyboard mapping application on Mountain Lion to map combinations like <kbd>CMD</kbd>+v to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> as I'm from a Windows background.
However its a bit a hit and miss. For instance Finder still uses <kbd>CMD</kbd>+v as does Ableton. 
Does anyone know how to map these keyboard combinations properly?

Comment: What keyboard mapping application are you using? Are you aware that you can also set keyboard shortcuts in the System Preferences? Go to `System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Application Shortcuts` and make a new shortcut for all applications that refers to the menu item `Paste` and is `CTRL+v`.

Comment: I've done this but in the case of Finder the Menu Item is called "Copy *Filename*" e.g. if the file I was trying to copy was test.txt it would say "Copy test.txt". The menu item name is is changing depending on the filename being copied. I suspect this is what the problem is. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: I think the simple question I want to ask is - is there a way of mapping the copy and paste commands across all applications on a Mac so I can use the control key instead of the command key

Comment: Does [this](http://superuser.com/a/81843/141595) solve it?

Comment: Yes but it messes up the keyboard layout when using RDP into a Windows Machine so I wrote a script which swaps the keyboard layout so I can quickly change it when I have to work in a virtual machine. I'll see how that works.